# How to restore Intel HD GPU hardware detection after removing failed NVidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel, gpu

I am running Ubuntu13.10 - I have a Dell Latitiude E6530 laptop, it has an Intel CPU+GPU and also an NVidia NVS 5200M GPU. After having a perfectly fine system running very nicely under the Intel HD built-in graphics I *foolishly* attempted the horror of installing the NVidia drivers. Cut a long story short, I got nowhere and have failed to get my system to return to using the Intel integrated graphics. I've tried the various obvious tricks (I've read a lot of forum posts!!) but I cannot get the Intel GPU drivers/hardware detection to come back.

I am currently running under 'nouveau' against the NVidia card, which is v.v.slow but at least I can see my screen to type this :(

Can anyone help me restore the original Intel graphics??

The really odd thing is that it looks like the Intel GPU has *vanished* from the available hardware list?

Here is the output from pertinent things:

uname -a

```
Linux KEVLINUX 3.11.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 11 18:48:34 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

dpkg -l | grep intel | awk '{print $2}'

```
intel-gpu-tools
intel-linux-graphics-installer
libdrm-intel1:amd64
libdrm-intel1:i386
xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

lspci |grep VGA

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108GLM [NVS 5200M] (rev a1)
```

lspci -k|grep Intel

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 35)
```

lshw -c video:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF108GLM [NVS 5200M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f6000000-f607ffff
```

inxi -G

```
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GF108GLM [NVS 5200M] 
           X.Org: 1.14.5 drivers: nouveau (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,intel) Resolution: 1600x900@60.0hz, 1680x1050@59.9hz 
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on NVC1 GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.2.0-devel
```

My friend has an identical laptop - running Mint, this is the output from his inxi -G:

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller 
           Card-2: NVIDIA GF108GLM [NVS 5200M] 
           X.Org: 1.13.3 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) FAILED: nouveau,intel Resolution: 1920x1080@60.2hz 
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 9.1.7
```

**^^^ this is what I would expect to see, both the Intel and the NVIDIA cards - mine is missing the Intel one now.** Notice also that the Intel GPU is *not* listed in my lspci output!

Also the first few lines of his lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

**^^^ Again, this is what I would expect to see!**

I've tried the obvious --reinstall of the X components including the -intel bits, but it makes no difference, I have tried adding intel section to the xorg.conf, it loads then unloads the intel driver. I guess because it doesn't think I have an intel GPU any more?!

I assume this is because of the horrid kernel level tinkering that the NVidia drivers did... It is possible to get the Intel VGA hardware to be detected again?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to re-enable Optimus in the Dell BIOS - under Video section. The Intel integrated GPU was then restored to the hardware list and Ubuntu correctly detected it and used the default drivers.

I don't actually remember changing that setting but in my flapping with the NVidia driver I must have tried that.